# Error reading rdd locally using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, rdd

I have a rdd stored locally and I am using jupyter notebook with pyspark. I tried to load the rdd but it crashed, stating file not found, although the files are there. Do you know the reason?

```
a=sc.textFile('file:///myfile/test5.rdd')
```

Error message

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in 
stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 303, abc.com, executor 3): 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/myfile/test5.rdd/part-00000 does not exist
```

Comment: How is the whole DAG looks like?

Comment: @Mariusz the sad thing is I can't access the DAG, I only have the logs

Comment: And the command failes just after the `sc.textFile` instruction? In what mode you run the application? yarn/local?